# creating a radio interface using java swing gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

I'm in a group assignment at university doing a swing GUI course and need some hints.

I have to develop and implement a user interface that represents the following below, knobs tuner slider and all.

but I have no idea where to start, note this image wasn't supplied by the lecturer but by other students in the group and are quite inflexible with the way it looks.

My 2 biggest problems are, the knobs, and the tuner.

Any idea's would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps use some kind of canvas (override drawing methods on standard panels) and draw the display. Same with knobs.

Comment: Personally I would go for a digital display ;-) . Not really sure what this has to do with learning Swing. Looks more like custom painting to me as you can hardly re-use any of the existing Swing components

Comment: "Not really sure what this has to do with learning Swing."
you and me both, but they designed it so I have to implement it.
I know its not really a stackoverflow type question, but this place is great when you need help and have no where else to turn.

Comment: Round dials don't work well in mouse controlled GUIs, use a `JSlider` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your own Knob class to work this out. You can start with a custom drawn component that's based on `JButton`. The tuner however must be drawn on a `JPanel` separately. There will be a lot of custom-code that will be implemented. Good luck :-)

You will have to look into :

1. `JPanel` and its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method
2. `JButton` and its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method
3. `Graphics2D` class.

For the knob, you can start with a custom drawn, image based JButton, implement `actionPerformed()` method for it, and `Graphics2D.rotate()` it. Design it with MVC pattern, where you set the angle of rotation and rotate it with the `paintComponent()`. That will set the necessary calibration for the model.

For the tuner, however, you can start with a .png based background, and a rectangle that can move around using methods from Graphics2D. This will be tied to the Radio-tuner model.

Its hard to explain in words. But I think you get the point.

Good luck.